# What is the literal translation of "私はこのうちを出ます"?

Tags: translation, words

I am trying to understand the bolded part of the following sentence:

> 春子は言いました。「わかりました。では、**私はこのうちを出ます**」

which translates to

> Haruko replied, "Okay. Well **I'll leave then.**"

Note this is spoken in the context of a relationship. So it could be further translated to "I'm leaving this romantic relationship with you".

**Question:** What does "私はこのうちを出ます" *literally* translate to?

**Attempt:**

- 私は = "As for me"
- この = "this"
- うち = "inside"
- 出ます = "leaving"

So is the literal translation

> "As for me, I'm leaving this inside"?

Is my translation totally wrong, or is this just the Japanese way of communicating "I'm leaving this romantic relationship"?

Comment: Context: do the speaker and listener live together?

Comment: I believe so, yes. The source of this sentence is the N5 reader found here: https://www.kanshudo.com/read/9hnvq0/intro (unfortunately, I think you have to register with Kanshudo to see the story).

Comment: （お）うち also means house

Comment: See this: [What's the Etymology for using うち to mean “I”?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/92770/43676)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's more like the end of living together than the end of a relationship.

In this case, うち means "house', and by extension, 'family'. So it's like saying "I'm leaving this house" or "I decided to stop living with you". It doesn't literally mean "I don't consider you and I are a family/couple any more" (although it may sometimes be implied).

私/僕はこのうちを出ます is typically said by a wife leaving her husband, a son leaving his parents, etc. It presupposes that the speaker and the listener have lived together.

(Strictly speaking, the quoted passage does not specify who the listener is, and it could be a third person, but it seems like under the most likely situation the listener is the person(s) left behind.)